# CKEditor don't work on my PC

Tags: google-chrome, ckeditor

some weird problem. Last week I installed CKEditor and it worked very well. Today it doesn't work anymore and only from my computer and Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94 m. It works from IE and Mozilla, I've tryed from other PC's with the same Chrome Version and it works fine.. Any Ideas what's the problem can be?

Comment: Add some more information, are there error messages? Do you see a default textbox? Have you tried to ctrl-F5? If you press F12 and access the developer console, do you see errors or warnings?

Comment: Ok I found out that If I press CKEditor's Source button and It allows me to write in textbox. But I cannot write if I haven't pressed this button.. I see CKEditors box with it's all buttons.. Only errors what I see after visiting this page is PPB_Graphics2D.PaintImageData: Rectangle is outside bounds.

Comment: Ok. Are the icons grayed or normal? Could you perhaps show us an URL or paste the code that you have including the CKEditor configuration if you have changed it? I could test using my chrome. What about plugins, do you have any custom plugins? It's hard to replicate without code or an URL :)

Comment: Ok thanks for idea about plugins. I've disabled all of them and now it works. I couldn't image that it can be plugin, because from last week I haven't added any of them or do smth with them. Thanks now it works good. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome sometimes seems to have issues with CKEditor plugins, for example the autogrow plugin.

Disabling plugins helped here.

Comment: Added as answer so that if people find this from Google or wherever they can see what solved it but I'm adding it as community wiki because I didn't really solve it.